# DATE to TimeStamp. HTML ZONA UTC

Tags: html, date, timestamp, timezone

Buen dia,

Tengo un input DATE el cual quiero pasar a timestamp,  el tema esta que cuando lo paso me arroja un día menos, esto es porque la zona horaria me la esta poniendo  GTM -0900, como puedo hacer para setear mi la zona horaria local, o no me considere las horas, solo necesitó la fecha sin hora  YYYY-mm-dd.

la respuesta que me aarroja es date: Mon May 11 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central)

```js
$('#queryDuties').on('click', function() {
    var dateJob = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
    var timestamp = ((Date.parse(dateJob)));
 })
```

```html
<legend>Itinerario de rutas</legend>
<div>
  <label for="start">Start date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="startDate" name="trip-start" value="<?php $today=date("Y-m-d "); echo $today;?>" min="<?php $today=date("Y-m-d"); echo $today;?>" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="queryDuties" type="button" value="Consultar" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `toLocaleString` para representar la fecha en cualquier zona horaria.
Obviamente, esta función devuelve un `string`, pero puedes usarlo luego para crear de nuevo otra `Date` pasándolo por el constructor.

Dejo [aquí](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/8481876) una lista de todas las zonas horarias disponibles. De esa lista, habría que pasar por parámetro la zona y la región.
*e.g.:* `'America/Menominee'`, `'Europe/Amsterdam'`, `'America/Kentucky/Louisville'`, ...

```js
document.querySelector(`#queryDuties`).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  var dateJob = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
  const str = toTimezone(dateJob, "Europe/Andorra");
  console.log(str);
});

const toTimezone = (date, timeZone) => 
  new Date(date).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone });
```

```html
<legend>Itinerario de rutas</legend>
<div>
  <label for="start">Start date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="startDate" name="trip-start" value="<?php $today=date("Y-m-d "); echo $today;?>" min="<?php $today=date("Y-m-d"); echo $today;?>" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="queryDuties" type="button" value="Consultar" />
</div>
```

Espero que sirva.